# Join on subquery with knex

Tags: sql, knex.js

What I'm trying to achieve is join on a subquery, i.e.:

```
select A.*, B.*, C.* from A
join C on C.id = A.c_id
join B on B.id = (
    select id from B
    where B.created_at > C.created_at
    order by B.created_at asc
    limit 1
)
```

What I've tried:

```
...
.leftJoin('B', 'B.id', knex.select(...
...
```

Which didn't work.
Also tried:

```
...
.leftJoin('B', function () {
  this.on('B.id', knex.select(...
})
...
```

Which also doesn't work. How can I achieve that with knex?

Comment: You might find it easier to just change the `ON` condition for the `JOIN B` to a `WHERE` condition. It should get optimised to the same query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like there is still some bugs in `knex`, when passing query builder to join.

Anyways, this is how you can achieve that query:

```
knex('A')
  .join('C', 'C.id', 'A.c_id')
  .join('B', 'B.id', (builder) => {
    builder
      .select('id')
      .from('B')
      .where('B.created_at', '>', knex.ref('C.created_at'))
      .orderBy('B.created_at', 'desc')
      .limit(1);
  })
```

https://runkit.com/embed/sqavpxeds1cn